# Reading messages from Discord-Client doesnt trigger event

Tags: python, discord

I properly used the discord developer portal to create a token and I also generated an OAuth2 link with the proper scopes - after I used the link and started my Python code it won't output any messages in the proper function.

```py
import discord

TOKEN="--hidden--"
id="--hidden--"
client=discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("Channel:"+message.channel)
    print("Author:"+message.author)
    print("Content:"+message.content)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

No error messages are shown, but the on_message function is never invoked - any ideas?

Comment: Do you see the "Logged in as" being printed?  Is the bot appearing as online in the discord app?

Comment: Yes, everything in the on_ready function was executed correctly, so it was printed. But I didn't find the bot in the discord app on the right hand side.